# highcharts: tooltip shows for spline but not scatter plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using this code for Highcharts tooltip generation:

```
tooltip: {
shared: true,
crosshairs: true,
formatter: function () {
    var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y, %H:00', this.x) + '</b>';

    $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
        s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + ' m/s';
    });

    return s;
}
```

}

It works perfectly for charts which use spline for the defaultSeriesType but it doesn't work for scatter charts.

See this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s83aT/ for both spline and scatter in action.

Any advice will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I see it is caused by shared option, when it is set as false then tooltips appears.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks, that did point me toward the solution I eventually implemented, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Sebastian Bochan pointed out that "shared: true" is part of the issue I looked into this some more and here is what I found out and how I ultimately solved the problem.  For whatever reason the Fiddle linked in the question was screwed up.

```
shared: true
```

is required if there is more than one series in the chart and one wants to have all series displayed in the same tooltip.  In my case this was a leftover from other plots I made but not needed in the single series plots my original question was about.

For single series plots "shared: true" should not be used.  It defaults to "shared: false" and thus "shared" doesn't need to be included at all.

Here's the formatter code which I am now using and it works for all single series, whether it's spline or scatter:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y, %H:00', this.x) +
                '</b> ' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' deg';
    }
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Reality_Extractor/pNFYL/ for both spline and scatter plots in action.